# Heroku translations issues in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku

I am currently working on pdf creation with wicked pdf it is working fine on local machine. Translations are working as per the requirements. I deployed the application on heroku and pdf showing square boxes instead of asian fonts in which it has been translated. Is there any way to dig this problem out or anyone from you faced the similar problem with heroku?

Comment: I have similar problem with Heroku dropping styles and a whole button element. Strange. Did you use Tailwind by any chance?

Comment: Wicked pdf requires it's own stylesheets. so you need to somehow embed them in the page that you're converting, rather than just linking to them, as per a usual web page